# compute mean with x range for many variables

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, purrr

I have many columns of continuous variables, and I need to compute how many of them are within x range. I tried a rather verbose approach similar to this:

```
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>% 
  mutate("1" = if_else(mpg  >= 0 & mpg  <= 1, 1, 0),
         "5" = if_else(mpg  >= 0 & mpg  <= 5, 1, 0),
         "10" = if_else(mpg  >= 0 & mpg  <= 10, 1, 0),
         "20" = if_else(mpg  >= 0 & mpg  <= 20, 1, 0),
         "50" = if_else(mpg  >= 0 & mpg  <= 50, 1, 0),
         "100" = if_else(mpg  >= 0 & mpg  <= 100, 1, 0),
         "400" = if_else(mpg  >= 0 & mpg  <= 400, 1, 0),
         distance = round(mpg , 2)) %>% 
  select("1", "5", "10", "20", "50", "100", "400") %>% 
  map_df(mean)
```

Is there an elegant way to iterate this processes without copy and pasting the variable?

Comment: Try `imap_dbl(lst(1, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 400), ~ with(mtcars, mean(between(mpg, 0, .x)))) %>% as_tibble_row`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we need to do this for all the numeric columns, loop over the upper range values, then use `summarise` with `across` to loop across the columns, calculate the `mean` of the logical vectors created with `between`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
imap_dfr(lst(1, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 400), ~ {
       ul <- .x
       mtcars %>% 
         summarise(across(where(is.numeric),
            ~ mean(between(., 0, ul))))}, .id = 'categ')
```

-output

```
#  categ    mpg     cyl    disp      hp drat      wt    qsec vs am gear    carb
#1     1 0.0000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000    0 0.00000 0.00000  1  1    0 0.21875
#2     5 0.0000 0.34375 0.00000 0.00000    1 0.90625 0.00000  1  1    1 0.93750
#3    10 0.0000 1.00000 0.00000 0.00000    1 1.00000 0.00000  1  1    1 1.00000
#4    20 0.5625 1.00000 0.00000 0.00000    1 1.00000 0.90625  1  1    1 1.00000
#5    50 1.0000 1.00000 0.00000 0.00000    1 1.00000 1.00000  1  1    1 1.00000
#6   100 1.0000 1.00000 0.15625 0.28125    1 1.00000 1.00000  1  1    1 1.00000
#7   400 1.0000 1.00000 0.90625 1.00000    1 1.00000 1.00000  1  1    1 1.00000
```

---

Or this can be done in `base R` with `outer`

```
categ <- c(1, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 400)
out <- cbind(categ, outer(categ, mtcars,
     Vectorize(function(x, y) mean(y >= 0 & y <= x))))
```

-output

```
out
#     categ    mpg     cyl    disp      hp drat      wt    qsec vs am gear    carb
#[1,]     1 0.0000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000    0 0.00000 0.00000  1  1    0 0.21875
#[2,]     5 0.0000 0.34375 0.00000 0.00000    1 0.90625 0.00000  1  1    1 0.93750
#[3,]    10 0.0000 1.00000 0.00000 0.00000    1 1.00000 0.00000  1  1    1 1.00000
#[4,]    20 0.5625 1.00000 0.00000 0.00000    1 1.00000 0.90625  1  1    1 1.00000
#[5,]    50 1.0000 1.00000 0.00000 0.00000    1 1.00000 1.00000  1  1    1 1.00000
#[6,]   100 1.0000 1.00000 0.15625 0.28125    1 1.00000 1.00000  1  1    1 1.00000
#[7,]   400 1.0000 1.00000 0.90625 1.00000    1 1.00000 1.00000  1  1    1 1.00000
```

Comment: Great solution! how would I transpose the output so the columns are the threshold?

Comment: @dano_ You can just use `t(out)` to get the expected

Answer (score 1):

This should give an identical result and is a fairly "tidy" way of doing it I think:

```
distance_thresholds <- tibble(
  threshold = c(1, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 400)
)

mtcars %>%
  left_join(distance_thresholds, by = character()) %>%
  group_by(threshold) %>%
  summarise(avg = mean(mpg <= threshold)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = threshold, values_from = avg)
```

Answer (score 0):

`sapply` with `colMeans` :

```
vals <- c(1, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 400)
colMeans(sapply(vals, function(x) mtcars$mpg >=0 & mtcars$mpg <= x))
```